# use libname with SAS enterprise guide (new settings)?

Tags: connection, sas

I have the following two lines extracted from the code:

```
signon task1;
rsubmit  connectwait=yes;     

/*************************************************/
/*                                               */
/*       Your SAS Code here                      */
/*                                               */
/*************************************************/

options nocenter FORMCHAR="|----|+|---+=|-/\<>*";

********************Read HCUP dataset into SAS*******************************;

libname mkts2013 "\\myfolder\project1"; /*data file*/
libname fov7dta "\\myfolder\project2";
```

It is working in the past, but now it does not work. The problem is in the above two libname statements. Does anyone know what is going on? Many thanks for your time and attention.

Comment: There's no way for us to tell without more information than you've provided.

Comment: When in the past? Where? on EG, on the same system, Base SAS? Did anything change? Most likely this is a server or network issue that we won't be able to help with anyways.

Comment: @Joe, many thanks. I am a SAS beginner. I am mainly asking this for a friend.

Comment: @Reeza, many thanks. I need to make sure.

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work?" It doesn't assign? It gives an error when you run it? There's no data in the library?

Answer (score 0):

I would speculate the folders on the remote machine have been removed, moved, renamed or protected such that client session no longer has rights to access the folders.  If the code is being run by person B and it worked for person A, then person B's login either does not have access rights or a pathway to the folders in question.

Happy hunting.